# QUERY_STRING handling in php

Tags: php, query-string, validating

It's possible via .htaccess send query to another file?
A bit explaining:

**index.php** handle all pages like this:

```
switch($page) {
    case 'index':
        require_once START . '/includes/pages/index.php';
    break;

    case 'another':
        require_once START . '/includes/pages/another.php';
    break;
       and so on...
```

In .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^index$ index.php?page=index [L]
RewriteRule ^another$ index.php?page=another [L]
```

Links(eg. **localhost/84ss7d41**):

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?QUERY_STRING=$1 [L]
```

So in **/includes/pages/index.php**:

```
if ($_GET['QUERY_STRING']) {
$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] = $_GET['QUERY_STRING'];
$query_string = check_input($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
    //checking/validating processing further...
```

How to make links like this one **localhost/84ss7d41** work in same way as now, but without **index.php** ? I'm trying to seperate my "project" if something would happen (files accidentally deleted) checking/validating data would work same, without main script, it's like:

```
if (main project file index.php/ || /includes/pages/index.php doesn't exist) {
  check/validate data with reserve.php
}
```

Comment: Do not overwrite members of the `$_SERVER` array if you want to stay out of trouble later. What you try to achieve should be possible w/o but you must make more clear what you try to achieve exactly.

Comment: Can you clarify your question? You want to create links like `localhost/84ss7d41` or you want to redirect user whenever the index.php does not exists? What do you want?

Comment: @MahanGM exactly, whenever the index.php does not exists

Comment: @ZeroSuf3r, There should be at least one `index` page to handle queries. I don't know what's your application architecture but I think the standard way is to have one major page in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*) /reserve.php [L]
```

This redirects all requests that do not match an existing file (for example, an image) to `index.php`, where you can then use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]` to decide how to act.  This is an implementation of the Front Controller pattern http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern

Additionally, if `index.php` cannot be found by apache, then the request will be forwarded to `reserve.php`

Although, building in this kind of redundancy is not necessarily the 'right' thing to do (what if reserve.php goes missing too?). Enforcing proper access controls over `index.php` is probably a better approach.

Comment: Which would obviously lead to one "index.php" but here called "controller.php"?

Comment: In fact it is the question I'm not gettin' here. Why would one kill the main-script? Besides that: I like the front controller pattern :)